# How to set multiple consumers in the same topic in Kafka using Quarkus

Tags: java, apache-kafka, reactive-programming, kafka-consumer-api, quarkus

I am building a Kafka consumer using Quarkus framework that will read a topic with 3 partitions. The code snippet below is working but based on the logs I am just initiating 1 consumer with 3 partitions. My problem now is how can I spawn 3 consumers once I run my application.

```
@Incoming("topic-1")
public CompletionStage<Void> onMessage(KafkaRecord<String, String> message) throws IOException {

    LOG.info("Kafka order message with value = {} arrived from topic {} ", message.getPayload(),
            message.getTopic());

    //JsonObject event = new JsonObject(message.getPayload());

    try {
        if (true) {
            LOG.info("Kafka message: " + message);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return message.ack();
}
```

Please see sample logs:

> INFO  [org.apa.kaf.cli.con.int.ConsumerCoordinator] (vert.x-kafka-consumer-thread-0) [Consumer clientId=testconsumer, groupId=kafka-detection-consumer] Finished assignment for group at generation 64: {testconsumer-bf6d314c-44e1-47b1-9439-fe4058951841=Assignment(partitions=[test_part-0, test_part-1, test_part-2])}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your application on containers platform (Docker, K8S ...) then you can scale your service horizontally; otherwise, run your application again with different port.

When Kafka client is started, It will be assigned to a certain partition, so same client cannot consume from multiple topic-partitions.

Comment: This can be an option but I what I want is to increase within the service maybe threads or other options that I can code within the service.

Comment: I didn't try it but maybe you can configure another channel name pointing to the same Kafka topic, and create two methods with common code but different channel name, I believe this should do.

Comment: Thanks! That's my last option but it will have a dirty code - I am looking for dynamic configuration and will spawn threads/consumers based on that config.

Comment: Also make sure that all your consumers use the same consumer-group-id.