# How to start multiple message consumers in Quarkus?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, vert.x, quarkus

I'm trying to migrate from Vert.x to Quarkus and in Vert.x when I write message consumers like Kafka/AMQP etc. I have to scale the number of verticals to maximize performance across multiple cores i.e. Vertical Scaling - is this possible in Quarkus? I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699811/how-to-set-multiple-consumers-in-the-same-topic-in-kafka-using-quarkus) but it wasn't answered.

For example, with Kafka I might create a consumer inside a vertical and then [scale](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_specifying_number_of_verticle_instances) that vertical say 10 times (that is specify the number of instances in the deployment to be 10) after doing performance testing to determine that's the optimal number. My understanding is that by default, 1 vertical = 1 event loop and does not scale across multiple cores.

I know that it's [possible](https://quarkus.io/blog/mutiny-vertx/) to use Vert.x verticals in Quarkus but is there another way to scale things like the number of Kafka consumers across multiple core?

I see that this type of scalability is configurable for things like Quarkus [HTTP](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config) but I can't find anything about message consumers.

Comment: For Kafka uses the `partitions` attribute. For AMQP we don't have the support yet (we never had the request).

Comment: @Clement part of my confusion is that in some places I see "manual thread management" using Executors e.g. ReactiveKafkaConsumer.java and in other places I see Verticals e.g. SnsVerticle.java. Any advice on which way to go for AMQP or other protocols that don't support vertical scaling?

Comment: You can consume the messages as a Multi and emit the messages on various threads. Something like `@Incoming("amqp") @Outgoin("out") Multi<AmqpMessage> dispatching(Multi<AmqpMessage> multi) { return multi.emitOn(executor); }`
However, be aware of the memory vs. throughput trade-off. The other (more common) solution is to scale up your application itself (using auto-scaling)

Comment: I'm aware of horizontal scaling but in my case it wastes memory and some CPU. I've found it's optimal to utilize at least 1-2 CPUs per "JVM." The problem with a single threaded AMQP consumer is that the broker isn't fast enough. I've found I need at least 4-10 consumers per JVM which isn't hard to do with thread pools or Vert.x verticals but does appear to be a challenge for AMQP. I will try the "Mutiny" vertical approach and report back.

Comment: @Clement I've posted my attempt to solve this and would greatly appreciate your review and feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Vert.x Verticle approach that overall I'm very happy with, but I wish there were better documentation on how to do this.

UPDATE - Field injection doesn't work with this example but constructor injection does work.

Lets say I want to inject this

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class CoffeeRepositoryService {

    public CoffeeRepositoryService() {
        System.out.println("Injection succeeded!");
    }
}
```

Here's my Verticle

```
package org.acme;

import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.impl.logging.Logger;
import io.vertx.core.impl.logging.LoggerFactory;
import io.vertx.mutiny.core.eventbus.EventBus;
import io.vertx.mutiny.rabbitmq.RabbitMQClient;
import io.vertx.mutiny.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer;
import io.vertx.rabbitmq.QueueOptions;
import io.vertx.rabbitmq.RabbitMQOptions;

public class RQVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(org.acme.RQVerticle.class);

  //This doesn't work - returns null
  @Inject
  CoffeeRepositoryService coffeeRepositoryService;

  RQVerticle() {} // dummy constructor needed
   
  @Inject // constructor injection - this does work
  RQVerticle(CoffeeRepositoryService coffeeRepositoryService) {
    //Here coffeeRepositoryService is injected properly
  }

  @Override
  public Uni<Void> asyncStart() {
    LOGGER.info(
        "Creating RabbitMQ Connection after Quarkus successful initialization");

    RabbitMQOptions config = new RabbitMQOptions();
    config.setUri("amqp://localhost:5672");
    RabbitMQClient client = RabbitMQClient.create(vertx, config);
    
    Uni<Void> clientResp = client.start();
    clientResp.subscribe()
        .with(asyncResult -> {
          LOGGER.info("RabbitMQ successfully connected!");
              
        });

      return clientResp;
  }
}
```

Main Class - injection doesn't work like this

```
package org.acme;

import io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus;
import io.quarkus.runtime.QuarkusApplication;
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.QuarkusMain;
import io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions;
import io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx;

@QuarkusMain
public class Main {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    Quarkus.run(MyApp.class, args);
  }

  public static class MyApp implements QuarkusApplication {

    @Override
    public int run(String... args) throws Exception {
      var vertx = Vertx.vertx();
      System.out.println("Deployment Starting");

      DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions()
          .setInstances(2);
      vertx.deployVerticleAndAwait(RQVerticle::new, options);

      System.out.println("Deployment completed");

      Quarkus.waitForExit();
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Main Class with working injection but cannot deploy more than one instance

```
package org.acme;

import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;
import io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

@ApplicationScoped
public class MainVerticles {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MainVerticles.class);

  public void init(@Observes StartupEvent e, Vertx vertx, RQVerticle verticle) {
    public void init(@Observes StartupEvent e, Vertx vertx, RQVerticle verticle) {
    DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions()
    .setInstances(2);
    vertx.deployVerticle(verticle,options).await().indefinitely();
  }
}
```

Std Out - first main class looks good

> 2021-09-15 15:48:12,052 INFO  [org.acm.RQVerticle] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-2) Creating RabbitMQ Connection after Quarkus successful initialization
>
> 2021-09-15 15:48:12,053 INFO  [org.acm.RQVerticle] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) Creating RabbitMQ Connection after Quarkus successful initialization

Std Out - second main class

> 2021-09-22 15:48:11,986 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main
> Thread) Failed to start application (with profile dev):
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't specify > 1 instances for
> already created verticle

Comment: LGTM! The duplication looks like a logging config issue (two output)

Comment: @Clement - thanks for the review. Last question - any idea why field injection doesn't work in verticles? I updated my code above to show why I think field injection doesn't work but constructor injection does.

Comment: It depends on how you created your verticle. Is it a bean?

Comment: How do you create it as a bean? The exact code is above - I create it like this       vertx.deployVerticleAndAwait(RQVerticle::new, options); - just in case I tried marking the Verticle with the @ApplicationScoped annotation but that didn't chance anything and didn't really make sense either. The CoffeeRepositoryService I'm injecting is obviously a bean.

Comment: Check https://quarkus.io/guides/vertx-reference#deploying-verticles. Basically, your verticle must be a bean and you deploy the instance directly. Not that it might be problematic with your creation strategy as Arc will the responsible for creating the instance of verticle and not you.

Comment: @Clement not sure how to do that approach because if I mark the Class as ApplicationScoped then I cannot deploy more than one instance right? You can see the exact code I'm using above and the error "Can't specify > 1 instances for already created verticle"

Comment: Overall the approach is works pretty well but I've requested full support from Quarkus for my use case here https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20359